# A bag contains 6 white buttons, 2 blue buttons. What is the probability that exactly one of the 3 buttons taken out is blue?

Tags: probability

A bag of spare buttons contains 6 white buttons and 2 blue buttons.  3  buttons were taken out of the bag at random without replacement. What is the probability that exactly one of the 3  buttons is blue?

I don't really know how to solve this. The answer should be $\frac{15}{28}$, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of ways to choose any $3$ out of $6W$ and $2B$:

$$\binom{6+2}{3}=56$$

---

The number of ways to choose $2W$ and $1B$ out of $6W$ and $2B$:

$$\binom{6}{2}\cdot\binom{2}{1}=30$$

---

Hence the probability of choosing $2W$ and $1B$ out of $6W$ and $2B$:

$$\frac{30}{56}=\frac{15}{28}$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the $3$ cases you draw the blue one one first draw, you draw it on second draw or you draw it during the last one :

**Blue on first draw** : $\frac{2}{8}\frac{6}{7}\frac{5}{6}$

**Blue on second draw** : $\frac{6}{8}\frac{2}{7}\frac{5}{6}$

**Blue on third draw** : $\frac{6}{8}\frac{5}{7}\frac{2}{6}$

Finally you sum the three cases, so the final probability is : $$\frac{2}{8}\frac{6}{7}\frac{5}{6}+\frac{6}{8}\frac{2}{7}\frac{5}{6}+\frac{6}{8}\frac{5}{7}\frac{2}{6}$$

I let you simplify the fractions.

Comment: +1 But consider giving hints and constructive questions to low quality posts instead of complete solutions.